# Multiple Methods named '-setTransform:' found

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, transform, cgaffinetransform

```
-(void)rotateView:(id)sender {
CGAffineTransform rotateTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, M_PI);
[sender setTransform:rotateTransform];//the error is shown here
}
```

I am getting this caution error that shows up and says Multiple methods named -setTransform: found. It only shows up when I have #import AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h in my header file. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: townsend: Please see my (edited) answer for a (just today published) blog post on pretty much the same problem, as the you're confronted with. Today's your lucky day! ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cast `sender` to the proper class type and the warning should go away:

```
[(YourClassHere *)sender setTransform:rotateTransform];
```

As `sender` is passed to `rotateView:` as type `id` Xcode cannot know what actual class type it is and by that which method to call.

Edit: Coincidentally just today **Matt Gallagher** of [**Cocoa With Love**](http://cocoawithlove.com) fame published an [**article**](http://cocoawithlove.com/2011/06/big-weakness-of-objective-c-weak-typing.html) about all kinds of issues caused by calling an ambiguous method on `id` in Objective-C.

Comment: A better solution would be to rename the `setTransform:` method on `YourClassName` class to avoid the conflict entirely.  But that may not be possible.